# Exporting TikZ figures to .EPS

Tags: tikz-pgf, eps, tikz-external, shell-escape

i'm trying to export a TikZ picture to .eps using the following on Win7 (MikTeX), compiling with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error 
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" &&
pdftops -eps "\image".pdf}}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}}
```

For some reason, this does not yield any .eps file (the figure will only be exported as .pdf) - can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You can compile your code without that settings using `latex` and then convert the `dvi` to `eps`.

Comment: Does it work manually? Here your example correctly calls `pdftops -eps image.pdf`. Do you get any error message?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Note that TeX does not receive exit codes - if `pdftops` fails for some reason, it will assume that all is well and you do not get feedback. The `external` lib only checks if a "suitable" result file exists (I am unaware of options to receive the exit code, by the way)

Comment: For single diagrams you could also use the `standalone` class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Before `\begin{document}`, add `\pgfrealjobname{file_name}`

Before `\begin{tikzpicture}`, add `\beginpgfgraphicnamed{file_name}` and after `\end{tikzpicture}`, add `\endpgfgraphicnamed`

In the folder containing the file: hold the `Shift` key and `right click` > `Open command window here`

In the newly opened PowerShell window, type:

1. latex --jobname=file_name-f1 nfile_name.tex
2. dvips file_name-f1.dvi
3. ps2eps file_name-f1.ps